# Showing $|cI −A| > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A ∈M_{n×n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix all entries in which are positive and let $c$ be a positive real number greater than the spectral radius of $A$. Show that $|cI −A| > 0$.

$c >\max\{\lambda_i|\lambda_i\in spec(A)\}$. Obviously $|cI-A|\neq 0$, since $c\notin spec(A)$, however, I cannot show this determinant positive.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)=|\lambda I-A|$ is a monic, if $c$ is greater than any of it's roots, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Yes, since $p(x)$ can be written as  products of $(x - \lambda_i )^{k_i}$, where $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as the matrix $A$ can have complex eigenvalues, as well, the assumption should be reformulated as
$$
c>\max\{\lambda_k: \lambda_k\,\,\text{real eigenvalue of}\,\,A \}.
$$

If $\lambda_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$ are the eigenvalues of $a$, then $c-\lambda_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$ are the eigenvalues of $cI-A$, and
$$
\det(cI-A)=\prod_{k=1}^n (c-\lambda_k).
$$
If $\lambda_k$ is real, then $c-\lambda_k>0$, due to the assumption.

If $\lambda_k$ is complex, then $\overline{\lambda}_k$ is also an eigenvalue, and 
$$
(c-\lambda_k)(c-\overline{\lambda}_k)=\lvert c-\lambda_k\rvert^2>0.
$$ 
Then, as the complex eigenvalues of a real matrix come in conjugate pairs, then
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n (c-\lambda_k)=\prod_{\text{$\lambda_k$ real}} (c-\lambda_k) \cdot \left(\prod_{\text{$\lambda_k$ complex}} |c-\lambda_k|^2\right)^{1/2}>0.
$$

**Edit.** It can be proved in a more elegant way.

We clearly have that
$$
\lim_{c\to\infty}\det(cI-A)=\infty,
$$
and $\det(cI-A)=0$ if and only if $c$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Therefore, because of the continuity of $f(c)=\det(cI-A)$, it follows that
$$
f(c)=\det(cI-A)>0, \quad\text{for all $c>\max\{\lambda_k: \lambda_k\,\,\text{real eigenvalue of}\,\,A\}$.}
$$